# CodeIgniter Ion Auth forgot password reset link does not contain server IP address

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

In my config file when base_url = 'http://my-static-ip/my-installation-folder'
then forgot password link works fine.
But when change my basr_url to 
base_url = '/my-installation-folder'
all applications work fine except forgot password link.

Email is going to the concerned user, but the reset password link does not contain the Server IP address.

This type of Error is coming.
**The page you were on is trying to send you to an invalid URL (http:///cmts/auth/reset_password/VRxmW90fSEXTLmuX.9sA5.7291ca1368f3cca425).**
 **If you do not want to visit that page, you can return to the previous page.**

Need help pl.

Comment: Why do you change `base_url`? It needs to be a full address complete with `http:` and ending in a `/`.

Comment: Change your `basic_url` to your base URL like 
if your project is in the root directory
`base_url = '[http://example.com]'`
Otherwise, `base_url = '[http://example.com/projcet_dir]'`

Comment: The correct way to set `base_url` is `$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';` in the file `application/config/config.php`.

Comment: Simple: don't change your base url to that...